# Filter nested loop in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

New to Vue, and I want to loop through each category and then display posts.

```
<section v-for="(category) in (categoryList)">
    <h2>{{category.title}}</h2>
    <div v-for="(post) in (sortedActivity, filteredList)">
        {{post.title}}
    </div>
 </section>
```

Something like the above.

The `sortedActivity` function is a simple sort and `filteredList` function is a search.

But how do I parse `{{category.title}}` to those functions within computed? I assume I want to update the current instance state with the category title? But not sure the easiest way to do that within the loop as it will change. Or if there is another method (not literal)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to first search for a category using `filteredList` and then sort using `sortedActivity`. In that case, you can use:

```
<section v-for="category in categoryList">
  <h2>{{ category.title }}</h2>
  <div v-for="post in sortedActivity(filteredList(category.title))">
    {{ post.title }}
  </div>
</section>
```

However, in general, you should create another sub-component like the following:

```
<category-posts :category="category" v-for="category in categoryList">
</category-posts>
```

Where each `category-posts` would be:

```
<section>
  <h2>{{ category.title }}</h2>
  <div v-for="post in sortedActivity(filteredList(category.title))">
      {{ post.title }}
  </div>
</section>
```

This would help you keep outer and inner loop separate and avoid recomputation of inner for-loop. Also, do not forget to use [`key` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State).

Comment: Makes sense but get the following— `_vm.filteredList is not a function"`

Comment: I assume this is because it's a computed function and cannot accept arguments?

Comment: @CHEWX yes that is right. It must be a normal function.

Comment: Is there not a better way for this, as I am not getting an infinite loop warning. What's the optimum way. Any reference appreciated.

Comment: @CHEWX, please consider sharing a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok, here is my data:

`[{'First Name': 'Tom', 'Last Name': 'French', 'Age', '39', 'Class': '3B'},{'First Name': 'Matt', 'Last Name': 'French', 'Age', '39', 'Class': '4B'},{'First Name': 'Harshal', 'Last Name': 'Patil', 'Age', '39', 'Class': ''}]`

I want to loop each Class and display the people in that class. If no class, or empty, then set to 'Clearing'.

I hope that helps.

-

For context, `sortedActivity()` is currently to sort by age within the table and `filteredList()` does a search.